# Remove content translation links from contact form

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm having a difficult time diagnosing a problem on a site I'm working on. By default on a multilingual site Drupal puts "content translation links" at the bottom of nodes. I've disabled the content translation links in favor of the language switcher block. However, on the contact form from the contact module I still have what look like content translation links at the bottom of the form (see screenshot below).

[image: screenshot of contact form]

In the screenshot the translation links that I don't want are labeled #1 and the language switcher block is labeled #2.

I've selected "hide content translation links" under /admin/settings/language/i18n , but I guess this doesn't apply to the contact form for some reason.

So far I've been able to deduce that these links are getting passed through the $content variable because when I remove `print $content` from page.tpl.php, the links (as well as the contact form itself, of course) disappear. It also seems that the links are being treated as part of the contact form itself; when I tried using the panels site contact page override, whenever I added the contact form widget the links were included.

I apologize if this is perhaps too "localized" (pardon the unintentional pun) a question, but any help with figuring out how to get rid of these content translation links from the contact form page would be greatly appreciated. On the one hand I highly doubt this is the expected default behavior, so I feel like I must have tripped a setting or missed a setting somewhere. But at the same time I've looked through pretty much everything I can think of, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: It can be helpful when you tag your post with the Drupal version you're using ('drupal-6', 'drupal-7' etc.)

Comment: Ah, I know... "Send e-mail", that's the Drupal 6 contact form.

Comment: I tried tagging it as drupal-6 but I got an error saying that drupal-6 was a new tag and it didn't show up on autocomplete. I meant to edit my post to say it was for D6, but I forgot. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a contact form problem only, you might be able to remove the links with `hook_form_alter` or alternatively css.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'm new to using hooks and custom modules, so I'll try to do some research and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide that button, you can use the [CSS Injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector) module, create a CSS class to apply to that data, and set `display:none !important`. It's not necessary to use a Drupal hook.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Drupal 7, you can put `hide($content['language']);` in node.tpl.php.

Answer (score 1):

This is not only a Drupal 6 issue, I had the same problem on Drupal 7 until I solved it and found this discussion. My solution was to implement `template_preprocess_node()` in template.php and simply unset `$variables['content']['links']['translation']`.

Unlike Laxman i couldn't find any data in `$content['language']` in node.tpl.php and I don't think such variable exist. You can try this with `var_dump($content['language']);` and you'll get an empty result. However, `var_dump($content['links']['translation']);` will result in an array containing information on what languages current node has translations for.

A lot of help came from reading about [translation_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!translation!translation.module/function/translation_node_view/7) in the Drupal API.